# cannot find a way to make it in a not operator in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    const int minAge = 16;
    const int maxAge = 18;
    int age = 0;

    printf("how ols ru?");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    if (!age>=minAge || age <= maxAge) 
    strong text
    {
        printf("no phone for u");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I need to give a phone for whoever is not between the ages of 16-18 how do i do it using ! operator?

Comment: you need to use parentheses to encapsulate the entire segment you wish to negate.

Comment: Are you required to use `!`? If not, remove it.

Comment: yes i got to use it

Comment: `if (!(age >= minAge && age <= maxAge))`

Comment: First, find an expression that solves "ages of 16-18" and then `!(expression)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if (!(age < minAge || age > maxAge))

Comment: see comment from @WhozCraig  in your question post.

Comment: i need to give a phone to ages 16-18. the flowing answer is going to switch true to false and phone would not be given to ages 16-18